# Angular Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[[object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object]]:

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

My app is developed using angular 14 and on each route navigation on my app after I have made a code migration using git mv command line, I am getting the following error.
[image]

I will take the example of navigation to the route "**login-AA**"
my app routes looks this way :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LabelResolver } from '@app/resolvers/label.resolver';
import { LoginLegacyCanLoad } from '@app/guards/login-legacy.can-load';
import { LoginClassicConnectionComponent } from '@app/login/components';

const labelResolver = {
  labels: LabelResolver,
};
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./login/login.module').then((m) => m.LoginModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    data: {
      module: 'site,link,login',
    },
    resolve: {
      labels: labelResolver,
    },
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./login/login.module').then((m) => m.LoginModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'login-AA',
    data: {
      module: 'site,link,login',
      type: 'classic',
    },
    resolve: {
      labels: labelResolver,
    },
    component: LoginClassicConnectionComponent,
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and my app.module.ts looks like this.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from '@app/app-routing.module';
import {
  ConfigurationAppService,
  ConfigurationInitService,
  ConfigurationUserService,
  EnvManagementService,
  GtmService,
  httpInterceptorProviders,
  TokenService,
} from '../../../webrc-lib-angular-module/dist/module';
import { appMockInitProvider } from '@app/providers/app.mock.init.provider';
import { environment } from '@app/env';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { LoginModule } from '@app/login';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { OldLoginModule } from '@app/login-old';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import { AppInitService } from '@app/services/app-init.service';
import { ThemeService } from '@app/services/theme.service';
import { LoginClassicModule } from '@app/login/components/login-classic-connection/login-classic.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    LoginModule,
    LoginClassicModule,
    OldLoginModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    appMockInitProvider,
    EnvManagementService,
    TranslateService,
    AppInitService,
    ThemeService,
    ConfigurationAppService,
    ConfigurationUserService,
    ConfigurationInitService,
    GtmService,
    TokenService,
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: getRouterBasename(),
    },
    ...httpInterceptorProviders,
    { provide: 'environmentContext', useValue: environment },
  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    registerLocaleData(localeFr);
  }
}

function getRouterBasename() {
  const nodeName = environment.rootPath;
  let pathname = window.location.pathname;
  if (pathname.indexOf(nodeName) > -1) {
    return pathname.replace(new RegExp(nodeName + '.*'), '') + nodeName;
  }
}
```

the error happen exactely when any route navigation is happening , please continue focusing on the scenario of navigation to the route "**login-AA**".
example from LoginContainerComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ConfigurationInitService, UserToken } from 'webrc-lib-angular-module';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-container',
  templateUrl: './login-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-container.component.scss']
})
export class LoginContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  user: UserToken;
  isFranceConnect: boolean;
  loginClassicDisabled: boolean;
  isFranceConnectDisabled: boolean;
  loginDisabledLabel: string;

  constructor(
    protected router: Router,
    protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    public translateService: TranslateService,
    private configInitService: ConfigurationInitService
  ) {
      this.loginDisabledLabel = '';
      this.user = null;
      if (
        this.isFranceConnect 
      ) {
        this.updateRouter();
      }
    }
 

  updateRouter() {
    this.router.navigate(['login-AA'], {});
  }
```

as I'm explaining the case where I'm navigating to the **login-AA** route now I will share the code of login-classic.module.ts which looks like this :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { WebrcLibAngularModule } from 'webrc-lib-angular-module';
import { LoginClassicConnectionComponent } from '@app/login/components';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginClassicConnectionComponent],
  imports: [WebrcLibAngularModule],
  providers: [TranslateService],
})
export class LoginClassicModule {}
```

here is the component

```
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {
  CasService,
  ConfigurationInitService,
  GtmService,
  NavigateService,
  nirValidator,
  PopinComponent
} from 'webrc-lib-angular-module';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-classic-connection',
  templateUrl: './login-classic-connection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-classic-connection.component.scss']
})
export class LoginClassicConnectionComponent implements OnInit {
  login = '';
  loginControl: FormControl;
  pwd = '';
  pwdControl: FormControl;
  captcha = '';
  email = '';
  hide: boolean;
  isLoading: boolean;
  PHASES = {
    oldLogin: {
      btnLabel: 'LOG_CC_BTN_LOGIN',
      btnCallback: this.doLogin.bind(this),
      hasErrors: this.hasErrorsLoginAndPassword.bind(this),
      initValidators: this.initValidatorsOldLogin.bind(this)
    },
    username: {
      btnLabel: 'LOG_COM_BTN_NEXT',
      btnCallback: this.goToPassword.bind(this),
      hasErrors: this.hasErrorsLoginPhase.bind(this),
      initValidators: this.initValidatorsUsername.bind(this)
    },
    password: {
      btnLabel: 'LOG_CC_BTN_LOGIN',
      btnCallback: this.doLogin.bind(this),
      hasErrors: this.hasErrorsPasswordPhase.bind(this),
      initValidators: this.initValidatorsPassword.bind(this)
    }
  };
  phase: {
    btnLabel: string;
    btnCallback: () => void;
    hasErrors: () => boolean;
    initValidators: () => void;
  };
  hasErrors: boolean;
  isSeparated: boolean;
  showCaptcha: boolean;
  showEmail: boolean;
  signupClassicDisabled: boolean;

  constructor(
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
    protected navigateService: NavigateService,
    protected configurationService: ConfigurationInitService,
    protected casService: CasService,
    protected gtmService: GtmService,
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    this.hide = true;
    this.isLoading = false;
  }

  goTo(link: string) {
    this.navigateService.navigate(link);
  }

  handleRedirect() {
    if (this.configurationService.isLoginAAActive) {
      this.goTo('signup/creation-compte/standard/1/votre-identite');
    } else {
      this.navigateService.goToHome();
    }
  }
}
```

I will add by prevention also the code of login.modules.ts where LoginClassicModule  is included

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { LoginRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';
import {
  LoginAideConnectionComponent,
  LoginBlocsComponent,
  LoginFranceConnectComponent,
} from './components';
import { LoginContainerComponent } from './containers';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { CasService, WebrcLibAngularModule } from 'webrc-lib-angular-module';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { LoginClassicModule } from '@app/login/components/login-classic-connection/login-classic.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginContainerComponent,
    LoginBlocsComponent,
    LoginFranceConnectComponent,
    LoginAideConnectionComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
    LoginRoutingModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    WebrcLibAngularModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    LoginClassicModule,
  ],
  providers: [CasService, TranslateService],
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

my code architecture looks this way

[image]